# How do I make a Welcome page for blog

Tags: javascript

I used this code for a welcome page on a blog. But when I click on any page, this welcome screen is showing first. I need it to be shown only once per user when they first login to my page.

```
<code>
  <div id="first_p" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 5px;">
    <a onclick="document.getElementById('main_p').style.display = 'block';document.getElementById('first_p').style.display = 'none';" href="#">
      <img src="www.test.jpg" border="0">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="main_p" style="display: none;">
</code>
```

How can I make it just appear once per login?

Comment: Don't use `[onclick]`, it's obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

If it is something like a loading screen, use a masking div with absolute position. Use cookies to make sure it is not displayed when the page is refreshed.

```js
$(function () {
  if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.getItem("visited") == null) {
      $("a").click(function () {
        $("#mask").fadeOut();
      });
    }
    else
      $("#mask").hide();  
  } else {
    $("a").click(function () {
      $("#mask").fadeOut();
    });
  }
  localStorage.setItem("visited", true);
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; padding: 0; margin: 0; list-style: none; text-decoration: none;}
#mask {position: fixed; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75); left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; z-index: 99;}
#mask .message {position: absolute; height: 60px; background-color: #fff; width: 50%; left: 25%; top: 50%; margin-top: -30px; text-align: center; border-radius: 20px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<div id="mask">
  <div class="message">
    <h2>Welcome to My Site</h2>
    <p><a href="#">Click here</a> to proceed.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/cowezugipu/edit?output**

The message appears only once.

Comment: thank you . how can i use cookies to make sure it is not displayed when the page is refreshed ?

Comment: @user5268051 Updating the answer. Please behold.

Comment: @user5268051 Updated. This works only in your local instance, not in the fiddle.

Comment: Don't use cookies for data that you only need on client-side. [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) would be better option.

Comment: @Gothdo Good idea... `:)`

Comment: @user5268051 Where did you try that?

Comment: I've tested on a blog . can anyone write a code with cookies or localStorage for my first post ?

Comment: @user5268051 Sure I can do that! `:)`

Comment: @Praveen Kumar .. Thank u ! im waiting for your replay :)

Comment: @user5268051 **Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/cowezugipu/edit?output**

The message appears only once.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar Thanks work now . but it have a small problem when i click on my pages Welcome Page show for 1 second then hide ! how can i fix it ?